# remove a volume if exists

Tags: docker, docker-volume

As part of my CICD deployment, there is a volume `my_volume` that gets created on `docker-compose build/up`, that needs deleting every deployment.
Therefore the CICID script calls `docker volume rm my_volume` before `docker-compose build/up`.
But if a build fails, subsequent builds will error out on `docker volume rm my_volume`, because the volume doesn't exist.

How can I remove this volume only if it exists?

Comment: What have you tried already?  Is Compose managing the volume?

Answer (score 0):

In order to ignore failure while calling "docker volume rm my_volume" use  the below order-

```
set +e
docker volume rm my_volume
docker-compose build/up
true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the errors:

```sh
docker volume rm ${some_volume} || true
```

Or you can start by making sure the project is completely down:

```sh
docker-compose down -v
docker-compose up -d
```

Or you can start labeling your volumes and containers when testing, and prune those labels:

```sh
docker volume prune -f --filter 'label=ci-test'
```